# Maximize V/M of a cone

Tags: calculus, geometry

I was given the following task: (in german)

[image]

What it says is the following: You have given a part of a circle with radius r and angle $\varphi$. This circle is then being folded into a cone. My task is to calculate $\varphi$ so, that the volume divided by the surface of the cone is maximal.

The solution was given and is the following:

$$\varphi = \sqrt{2}\pi$$

But my result looks different:

Let's start by looking at the circle.

- Let $l$ be the circumference of the circle
- $r$ will be equal to 1
- Let $u$ be the circumference of the cones baseplate
- The height of the cone is donated by $h$
- The radius of the baseplate of the cone is donated by $k$

\begin{align}
l & = 2\pi \cdot r \cdot \dfrac{\varphi}{2\pi} \\
& = 2\pi \dfrac{\varphi}{2\pi}\\
& = \varphi
\end{align}

Lets get to the baseplate.
\begin{align}
k & = \dfrac{u}{2\pi} \\
& = \dfrac{\varphi}{2\pi}
\end{align}

This means that the area will be:

\begin{align}
A & = \pi k^2 \\
& = \pi \left(\dfrac{\varphi}{2\pi}\right)^2 \\
& = \dfrac{\varphi^2}{4 \pi}
\end{align}

The height of the cone can be calculated by using the 
sentence of the pythagoras:

$$h = \sqrt{1-k^2}$$

The last thing I need is the area of the circle (the unfolded cone):

$$M = \pi \dfrac{\varphi}{2 \ pi} = \dfrac{\varphi}{2}$$

I used a function to find the maximum point of the volume/area:

$$f(\varphi) = \dfrac{V}{M} = \dfrac{\frac{1}{3}A\cdot h}{\frac{\varphi}{2}} = \dfrac{\frac{1}{3}\dfrac{\varphi^2}{4 \pi}
\cdot \sqrt{1-{\dfrac{\varphi}{2\pi}
}^2}}{\frac{\varphi}{2}} $$

For simplification I removed every constant that has no influence on the point of the maximum:

$$f(\varphi) = \dfrac{\varphi^2
\cdot \sqrt{1-{\left(\dfrac{\varphi}{2\pi}
\right)}^2}}{\varphi}$$

But when calculating the maximum I get $$\varphi = \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\pi}$$

Does someone know what I did wrong?

Comment: Everything looks fine until the very end. Whatever’s going wrong is in the calculation of the maximum that you’ve elided.

Comment: The maximum of the function looks right for me, too. Maybe there is a mistake in the solution!?

Comment: The derivative of $ \phi \sqrt (1- \frac {\phi^2} {4\pi^2}) $ gives $ 1-\frac {\phi^2} {4\pi^2} - \frac {\phi^2} {4\pi^2} = 0. $ So, $ \phi = \pi \sqrt 2.$